# SUM and GROUP BY and Difference of colums

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum

i have a table t1

```
ag_name   ag_start    ag_end
a         10          20
c         30          50
a         60          70
c         70          75
```

i want to have this :

```
ag_name   numberOfCards
a         20
c         25
```

which means a has (20-10) + (70-60) = 20 Cards.

then please help me with the QUERY ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ag_name, sum(ag_end - ag_start)
from the_unknown_table
group by ag_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    ag_name, 
    sum(ag_end-ag_start) NoOfCards
From t1 
group by ag_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SUM(ag_end - ag_start) as numberofcards, ag_name From table
Group by ag_name
```

Answer (score 0):

the query works fine when i click on go in DirectAdmin , but when i write the code to show the recordset it shows different result . 
my model :

```
public function getAgents(){

$db =JFactory::getDBO();    
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT *,SUM(ag_end - ag_start) AS ag_num FROM #__basak_agent group by ag_fname";
$db->setQuery($query_Recordset1);
return $db->loadAssoc();

}
```

and this is my .php code :

```
</thead>   <?php   
    $count=0;   
        $result=$this->get('Agents');
        foreach( $result as $row_Recordset1 )
        {
            $count++;
?>
<tr>

        <td> <?php echo $count ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row_Recordset1['ag_fname'] ; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row_Recordset1['ag_lname'] ; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row_Recordset1['ag_num'] ; ?></td>

</tr>
        <?php  }        ?>
</table>
```

but in code shows :

```
1    a   a   a
2    a   a   a
3    2   2   2
```

there is no field like this in table , i dont know where it comes from ??! 
anybody have suggestion , where i have to look for it ? what is wrong with my code ?